# What are the credentials for Ubuntu 19.04 deployed via OVA?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, esxi

I've deployed the [Ubuntu 19.04 OVA from the Ubuntu website](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/disco/release/) using `ovftool`:

```
ovftool \
  --acceptAllEulas \
  --name=djtest \
  --prop:password=password \
  --datastore=datastore1 \
  --net:"VM Network"="VM Internal Network 1" \
  ubuntu-19.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova \
  <URL redacted>
```

However, when I try to log into the VM, the password `password` is rejected. I'm assuming the user is either `ubuntu` or `root`, but the supplied password fails for both. There is no property in the OVF file to specify a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out ESXi ignores the OVF data unless when using `ovftool` you provide the undocumented flag `--X:injectOvfEnv`, as explained here https://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2014/06/an-alternate-way-to-inject-ovf-properties-when-deploying-virtual-appliances-directly-onto-esxi.html, or when using `govc` you set `"InjectOvfEnv": true` in the spec JSON.